If $X$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process, is $\tilde X:=X-\lfloor X\rfloor$ Markov as well?
Assume $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is an $\mathbb R^d$-valued time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P_x)$ satisfying $\operatorname P_x[X_0=x]=1$ and let $$\iota:\mathbb R^d\to[0,1)^d\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor.$$ Is $$\tilde X_t:=\iota(X_t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ then again a (time-homogeneous) Markov process? It's transition semigroup then would most probably be $$\tilde\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;):=\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;)\circ\iota^{-1}\tag2\;\;\;\text{for }x\in[0,1)^d\text{ and }t\ge0.$$ I actually don't see what should go wrong: If $\mu$ is any probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ and $X\sim\mu$, then clearly $\iota(X)\sim\mu\circ\iota^{-1}$. However, Proposition 1-iv in this paper seems to claim that $\tilde X$ is not Markov anymore ... Is this really true?
EDIT I'm actually not sure about the definition of $\tilde k_t$. It could also be $$\tilde\kappa_t(x,B)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\kappa_t(k+x,k+B)$$ or even $$\tilde\kappa_t(x,B)=\sum_{k,l\in\mathbb Z^d}\kappa_t(k+x,l+B)$$ whereas $(2)$ corresponds to $$\tilde\kappa_t(x,B)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\kappa_t(x,k+B)$$ for $x\in[0,1)^d$ and $B\in\mathcal B([0,1)^d)$.

To be sure, we are applying the floor function coordinate-wise to $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

@NapD.Lover Yes, exactly.

Just define a 3-state discrete time Markov chain ${X_t}{t=0}^{\infty}$ with states $S={0, 1, 1.5}$ and transition probabilities $P{0,1}=P_{1,1.5}=1$ and $P_{1.5,0}=P_{1.5,1}=0.5$. This is irreducible and aperiodic. Define $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then $f(X_t)=0.5$ if and only if $X_t=1.5$ and $$P[f(X_{t+1})=0.5|f(X_t)=0, f(X_{t-1})=0]=1$$ $$P[f(X_{t+1})=0.5|f(X_t)=0, f(X_{t-1})=0.5]=1/2$$ so $f(X_t)$ is not a Markov chain.

If there exists a Markov dynamics where merging some states ruins Markovianity, we can embed that structure into this setting by setting the merged states to have the same fractional parts. Such dynamics do exist (and indeed, it is a standard exercise to find them in a class on Markov chains; if you haven't done this, try now), so you can construct counterexamples for your statement through these.

@Michael I see that this seems to be a counter example. On the other hand, isn't a measurable transform of a Markov process again a Markov process? And $\iota$ is clearly (Borel) measurable. So, what am I missing?

@stochasticboy321 Please also take note of my comment above.

@Michael There are continuous, which will ensure that the transformed process is again Markov. I'm not interested in the most general case, but particularly when the process is given by a SDE. Please check out my question on mathoverflow on that: https://mathoverflow.net/q/472242/91890.

It is not true that a measurable and/or continuous transformation of a Markov process is a Markov process, as my counter-example shows.

@Michael Yes, I know, but there are conditions on the transformation that ensure that the transformed process is again Markov. See my edit in the mathoverflow question.


This answer just details the counter-example from my comment.
Consider a 3-state dicrete time Markov chain $\{X_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ with states $S = \{0, 1, 1.5\}$
and transition probabilities
$$ P_{0,1}=1, P_{1,1.5}=1, P_{1.5, 0}=P_{1.5,1}=1/2$$
This is an irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain.
Define the fractional part function by $f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(X_t)=0.5 &\iff X_t = 1.5\\
f(X_t)=0 &\iff X_t \in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align}
&P[f(X_{t+1})=0.5|f(X_t)=0, f(X_{t-1})=0] = 1\\
&P[f(X_{t+1})=0.5|f(X_t)=0, f(X_{t-1})=0.5]=1/2
\end{align}
so $\{f(X_t)\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ is not a Markov chain.

I've asked a separate question for my concrete situation of Brownian motion. Maybe you can take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925850/what-is-the-transition-semigroup-of-toroidally-wrapped-brownian-motion

In general, if $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an $E$-valued Markov process, and $f:E \to F$ is a function, $(f(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is not a Markov process. Loosely speaking, for most Markov processes and most $f$, $(f(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ won't be Markov. But of course it's also true that $f(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is Markov in many natural cases, for example, in your, if e.g. $X_t$ is Brownian motion, or any Levy process for that matter.
The counterexample provided by Michael shows indeed $X_t - [X_t]$ isn't Markov in general. But a useful exercise would be to consider the reverse question: given a function $f$, what properties would a Markov process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ have to possess in order for $f(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ to be Markov? This is is the topic of the following brilliant paper:
Rogers, L. C. G.; Pitman, J. W., Markov functions, Ann. Probab. 9, 573-582 (1981). ZBL0466.60070..

Thank you for your answer. How do you prove that the claim is true when $X_t$ is a Lévy process? I'm really interested in that. I've tried to consider this particular scenario, but the special structure of $X_t$ didn't help me to show the claim.

The Markov property of a Markov process $X_t$ simply means that $X_{s+t}$ and $\mathcal F^X_s:=\sigma(X_r,r\le s)$ are conditionally independent given $X_s$. Now, since $\tilde X_r$ is $\sigma(X_r)$-measurable for all $r\ge0$, we clearly got $\sigma(\tilde X_{s+t})\subseteq\sigma(X_{s+t})$ and $\mathcal F^{\tilde X}s\subseteq\mathcal F^X_s$ which in turn implies that $\tilde X{s+t}$ and $\mathcal F^{\tilde X}$ are conditionally independent given $X_s$. However, what we actually need is conditional independence given the smaller system $\sigma(\tilde X_s)$.

As the counter examples have shown, we will not be able to obtain that in general. And, unfortunately, I don't see how the special assumption that $X$ is a Lévy process helps. By the aforementioned argumentation, I'm stuck at $$\operatorname E\left[f(\tilde X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F^{\tilde X}s\right]=\operatorname E\left[f(\tilde X{s+t})\mid X_s\right]$$

Please see my corresponding question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925850/what-is-the-transition-semigroup-of-toroidally-wrapped-brownian-motion

If $(X_t){t \geq 0}$ is a Levy process, then $X{t+s} - X_t$ is independent of $(X_u){u \in [0,t]}$. In particular, $[X{t+s}-X_t]$ is independent of $([X_u]){u \in [0,t]}$ (since if $(X_i){i \in I}$ and $(Y_j){j \in J}$ are independent, $(f_i(X_i)){i \in I}$ and $(g_j(Y_j)){j \in J}$ are independent). It follows that the law of $[X{t+s}]$ given $([X_u]){u \in [0,t]}$ is that of $[[X{t+s}-X_t]-[X_t]]$, which depends only on $([X_u]){u \in [0,t]}$ via $[X_t]$. Thus $([X_t]){t \in [0,t]}$ is Markov.

If you wanted to be really fancy, you could probably argue that if $(X_t){t \geq 0}$ is a Levy process on a Lie group $G$, and $f:G \to H$ is a Lie group homomorphism, then $(f(X_t)){t \geq 0}$ is a Levy process (and hence a Markov process) on $H$.

I'd also like to extend this result to the case where $B$ is replaced by a SDE with periodic drift and diffusion coefficients. Maybe you can take a look at my question for that as well: https://mathoverflow.net/q/472242/91890?
