What is the transition semigroup of toroidally wrapped Brownian motion?
More generally, let $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $\mathbb R^d$-valued Lévy process and $W:=\iota(B)$, where $$\iota:\mathbb R^d\to[0,1)^d\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor$$ (the floor function is applied componentwisely). I was able to show$^1$ that $W$ is again a time-homogeneous Markov process. However, I fail to identify its transition semigroup.
Let $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ denote the transition semigroup of $B$. In the present setting, that means $$(\kappa_tf)(x)=\operatorname E\left[f(x+B_t)\right].$$
Now let $\mu_t:=\mathcal L(B_t)$ denote the distribution of $B_t$. We should clearly have that the distribution of $W_t$ is $$\mathcal L(W_t)=\mu_t\circ\iota^{-1}\tag5.$$ For that reason, my candidate for the transition semigroup of $W$ was $$\tilde\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;):=\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;)\circ\iota^{-1}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in[0,1)^d.$$ But this seems to be wrong (most probably due to the way I treated $x$).
In fact, if $f,g:[0,1)^d\to\mathbb R$ are bounded and Borel measurable, I get \begin{equation}\begin{split}\operatorname E\left[f(W_s)g(W_{s+t})\right]&=\int\mu_s({\rm d}x)(f\circ\iota)(x)(\kappa_t(g\circ\iota))(x)\\&=\int\mu_s({\rm d}x)(f\circ\iota)(x)(\tilde\kappa_tg)(x),\end{split}\tag6\end{equation} where I've used that $(B_s,B_{s+t})\sim\mu_s\otimes\kappa_t$. This is still not the form we need. So, how can we proceed and how is the correct definition for the transition semigroup of $W$?

$^1$ $B_{s+t}$ and $\mathcal F^B_s:=\sigma(B_r,0\le r\le s)$ are conditonally independent given $B_s$. Since $W_r$ is $\sigma(B_r)$-measurable and consequentially $\sigma(W_r)\subseteq\sigma(B_r)$ for all $r\ge0$, we conclude that $W_{s+t}$ and $\mathcal F^W_s$ are conditionally independent given $B_s$. That is, $$\operatorname E\left[f(W_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F^W_s\right]=\operatorname E\left[f(W_{s+t})\mid B_s\right]\tag1.$$ Note that we can write $$\operatorname E\left[f(W_{s+t})\mid B_s\right]=\operatorname E\left[f(\iota(W_s+B_{s+t}-B_s)\mid B_s\right].\tag2$$ So far, this remains true if $X$ would just be any time-homogeneous Markov process. Now we use that $B_{s+t}-B_s$ and $B_s$ are independent to conclude $$\operatorname E\left[f(W_{s+t})\mid B_s\right]=\left.\operatorname E\left[(f\circ\iota)(x+B_{s+t}-B_s)\right]\right|_{x\;=\;W_s}\tag3$$ to conclude $$\operatorname E\left[f(W_{s+t})\mid B_s\right]=\operatorname E\left[f(W_{s+t})\mid W_s\right]\tag4.$$

Your guess is indeed correct. The transition kernel $\tilde{\kappa}_t$ for $(W_t)$ is given by
$$ \tilde{\kappa}_t(x, \cdot) = \kappa_t \circ \iota^{-1}, \tag{1}\label{e:1} $$
or using a more elementary notation,
$$ \tilde{\kappa}_t(x, E) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^d} \kappa_t(x, k + E) $$
for any $x \in [0, 1)^d$ and for any Borel subset $E$ of $[0, 1)^d$.

In order to prove this, it is better to make a clear distinction between $[0, 1)^d$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $[0, 1)^d$ as a quotient space induced by the map $\iota$. To this end, we change the notation and write
$$ \mathbb{T}^d = (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^d $$
for the $d$-dimensional torus obtained by the quotient map $ \iota : x \mapsto x \text{ mod } 1 $. Then proving the statement $\eqref{e:1}$ amounts to establishing:

Theorem. Let $\tilde{\kappa}_t : \mathbb{T}^d \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{T}^d) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$ \tilde{\kappa}_t(x, E) = \kappa_t(x', \iota^{-1}(E)) $$
for any $x' \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\iota(x') = x$ and $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{T}^d)$. Then $\tilde{\kappa}_t$ is the well-defined transition semigroup of $W$.

Proof. Let $f : \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be any bounded Borel-measurable function. Then for any $x' \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\iota(x') = x$, the change of variables formula gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(W_t)]
&=  \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(\iota(B_t))] \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(\iota(y)) \, \kappa_t(x', \mathrm{d}y) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{T}^d}  f(z) \, \kappa_t(x', \iota^{-1}(\mathrm{d}z)). \tag{2}\label{e:2}
\end{align*}
Moreover, we know that for any other $x'' \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\iota(x'') = x$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}^{x''}[f(W_t)]
&= \mathbf{E}^{0}[f(\iota(x'' + B_t))] \\
&= \mathbf{E}^{0}[f(\iota(x' + B_t))] \\
&= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(W_t)]. \tag{3}\label{e:3}
\end{align*}
Combining $\eqref{e:2}$ and $\eqref{e:3}$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\kappa_t(x', \iota^{-1}(\cdot)) = \kappa_t(x'', \iota^{-1}(\cdot))
\end{align*}
for any $x', x'' \in \iota^{-1}(x)$, which in turn proves that $\tilde{\kappa}_t(x, \cdot)$ is well-defined. Furthermore, rephrasing $\eqref{e:2}$ in terms of $\tilde{\kappa}_t$ gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(W_t)]
= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(\iota(B_t))]
= \int_{\mathbb{T}^d}  f(z) \, \tilde{\kappa}_t(x, \mathrm{d}z)
= (\tilde{\kappa}_t f)(x).
\end{align*}
Next, let $f, g : \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded Borel-measurable functions. Also, let $x \in \mathbb{T}^d$ and choose any $x' \in \iota^{-1}(x)$. Then by the Markov property of $B$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(W_s)g(W_{s+t})]
&= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(\iota(B_s))g(\iota(B_{s+t}))] \\
&= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(\iota(B_s))\mathbf{E}^{B_s}[g(\iota(B_t))]] \\
&= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(\iota(B_s))\mathbf{E}^{B_s}[g(W_t)]] \\
&= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(\iota(B_s)) (\tilde{\kappa}_t g)(\iota(B_s))] \\
&= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[f(W_s) (\tilde{\kappa}_t g)(W_s)] \\
&= (\tilde{\kappa}_s (f \cdot \tilde{\kappa}_t g))(x).
\end{align*}
In particular, when $f \equiv 1$, this reads as
\begin{align*}
(\tilde{\kappa}_{s+t} g)(x)
= \mathbf{E}^{x'}[g(W_{s+t})]
= (\tilde{\kappa}_s \tilde{\kappa}_t g)(x),
\end{align*}
establishing the semigroup property as needed.

Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure: You don't meant to disagree with the one I gave, right? Or do you see a mistake in there?

I'd also like to extend this result to the case where $B$ is replaced by a SDE with periodic drift and diffusion coefficients. Maybe you can take a look at my question for that as well: https://mathoverflow.net/q/472242/91890.

@0xbadf00d I think I agree with the one you have :)

The candidate $(\tilde \kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ actually is the transition semigroup of $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ and we can prove this as follows: Let $f,g:[0,1)^d\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and Borel measurable. Then, \begin{equation}\begin{split}\operatorname E\left[f(W_s)g(W_{s+t})\right]&=\operatorname E\left[(f\circ\iota)(X_s)(g\circ\iota)(X_{s+t})\right]\\&=\int\mathcal L(X_s)({\rm d}x)(f\circ\iota)(x)(\kappa_t(g\circ\iota))(x)\\&=\int\mathcal L(X_s)({\rm d}x)f(\iota(x))(\kappa_t(g\circ\iota))(\lfloor x\rfloor+\iota(x))\\&=\int\underbrace{(\mathcal L(X_s)\circ\iota^{-1})}_{=\;\mathcal L(W_s)}({\rm d}x)f(x)(\underbrace{\kappa_t(g\circ\iota)}_{=\;\tilde\kappa_tg})(\underbrace{\lfloor x\rfloor}_{=\;0}+x)\\&=\int\mathcal L(W_s)({\rm d}x)f(x)(\tilde\kappa_tg)(x)\\&=\operatorname E\left[f(W_s)(\tilde\kappa_tg)(W_s)\right].\end{split}\end{equation}
In the third equation, we simply added 0. In the fourth equation, we applied a general result about integration with respect to a pushforward measure. The only thing where I was unsure about is the $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$ in the fourth line. It came a bit too handy in here. However, it should actually be correct. If not, please let me know in the comments below.
